# SELECT [GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}

Tags: mysql

**SELECT GROUP BY で、「col_name」以外で、「expr」と「position」を指定できるみたいですが、どういう意味でしょうか？**

```
SELECT [GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}
```

[MySQL 5.6 リファレンスマニュアル   SELECT 構文](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/select.html)

---

**expr**
・expressionの略？
・[集約関数](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/group-by-functions.html)のこと？

---

**position**
・[position関数](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/string-functions.html#function_position)のこと？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> expr
>   expressionの略？
>   集約関数のこと？

*expression*は式で、`GROUP BY column1 + column2`のように式の計算結果でグループ化できるという意味です。

> position
>   ・position関数のこと？

`SELECT`句の*position*番目のフィールドでグループ化するという意味で、たとえば

```
SELECT column1, COUNT(*)
  FROM table
 GROUP BY 1
```

は`GROUP BY column1`と等価です。